# Letter Count - How to return the first word with the highest amount of repeating letters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, reduce

For example: "Today, is the greatest day ever!" should return greatest because it has 2 e's (and 2 t's) and it comes before ever which also has 2 e's. If there are no words with repeating letters return -1. Words will be separated by spaces.
Input:"Hello Apple Pie"
Output should be:"Hello"
Do not understand what is wrong with my code, also if you think there is a simpler and shorter way to solve I would love to hear it. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
  function LetterCountI(str) { 
    let unique=[... new Set(str)]
    if(unique==str){ 
      return -1}
    
    let arr= str.split(" ") 
    
    let array=arr.map(item=>{ 

    let temparr=item.split("")

      return temparr.reduce((acc,curr)=>{ 
    acc[curr]=acc[curr]? acc[curr]+1:1 
    if(acc[curr]>acc.max){ 
      acc.max=acc[curr]}
return acc},{max:1, word:item})}) 
    
    let amount=1
    let largest=""
    
    for(let item of arr){ 
      if( item.max>amount){ 
        amount=item.max 
        largest=item.word
      }
    } 
    
    return largest
    
   }
```

Comment: `unique` becomes an array so your first `if` is pointless to compare to the original `str`. This snafu kinda infers that you also dont understand the rest of your code attempt. ... If so, why not attempt a different solution that is within your programming knowledge? You don't *have* to use reduce to solve this that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the simpler problem of getting the frequency of each letter in a word...

```
// given "sassy", will return { s:3, a:1, y:1 }
function letterFrequency(word) {
  return word.split('').reduce((acc, letter) => {
    if (!acc[letter]) acc[letter] = 0;
    acc[letter]++;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

A simple problem to get the max frequency...

```
// given { s:3, a:1, y:1 }, will return 3
function maxLetterFrequency(word) {
  return Math.max(...Object.values(letterFrequency(word)));
}
```

Another simple problem to sort a sentence by frequency...

```
// given "She sells seashells by the seashore"
// returns ["seashells", "sells", "seashore", "She", "by", "the"]
function wordsOrderedByMaxLetterFrequency(sentence) {
  let words = sentence.split(' ');
  words.sort((a, b) => {
    return maxLetterFrequency(b) - maxLetterFrequency(a);
  });
  return words;
}
```

The first word in the resulting array is the answer.  You can retest max frequencies in that word to determine of the answer should be -1.

Demo...

```js
// given "sassy", will return { s:3, a:1, y:1 }
function letterFrequency(word) {
  return word.split('').reduce((acc, letter) => {
    if (!acc[letter]) acc[letter] = 0;
    acc[letter]++;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

// given { s:3, a:1, y:1 }, will return 3
function maxLetterFrequency(word) {
  return Math.max(...Object.values(letterFrequency(word)));
}

// given "She sells seashells by the seashore"
// returns ["seashells", "sells", "seashore", "She", "by", "the"]
function wordsOrderedByMaxLetterFrequency(sentence) {
  let words = sentence.split(' ');
  words.sort((a, b) => {
    return maxLetterFrequency(b) - maxLetterFrequency(a);
  });
  return words;
}

const sentence = "She sells seashells by the seashore";
const sorted = wordsOrderedByMaxLetterFrequency(sentence);
console.log(sorted);
console.log('best word:', sorted[0]);
console.log('max freq in best word:', maxLetterFrequency(sorted[0]));
```

Comment: Thank you really danh for breaking up the code for me and explaining the concepts I wasn't fully understanding. I wish more  of the stack overflow community was like you. Thanks again this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My initial approach would involve separating out a `maxBy` function that accepts a function extracting a comparison number from an input value and returns a function from a list of values to the largest one of those.

Then we could write `letterCount` to count the occurrences of various letters in a string, and wrap that up with a function, `maxLetterCount` that calculates the maximum letter count for a string, using `Math .max` on the values from `letterCount`, and write our main function to split your initial string into words and call `maxBy` using `maxLetterCount` against the list of words.  It could look like this:

```js
// DO NOT USE -- Doesn't meet all requirements!

const maxBy = (fn) => (xs) => xs .reduce (
  ({m, r}, x) => {const v = fn(x); return v > m ? {m: v, r: x} : {m, r}}, 
  {m: -Infinity}
) .r

const letterCount = ([...cs]) => 
  cs .reduce ((a, c) => {a [c] = (a [c] || 0) + 1; return a}, {})

const maxLetterCount = (cs) => 
  Math .max (... Object .values (letterCount (cs)))

const letterCountI = (s) =>
  maxBy (maxLetterCount) (s .split (/\s+/))

console .log (letterCountI ("Today, is the greatest day ever!"))
console .log (letterCountI ("Hello Apple Pie"))
```

But there is a problem with this approach.  It doesn't take into account your requirement that if there are no duplicated letters, we must return `-1`.  Right now, `letterCountI ("Today is the day")` will return `"Today"`.

One fix for this problem might involve pairing the words with their max letter counts, filtering these pairs to only those which have multiply-occurring letters, then use `maxBy` again on the pairs, and finally pull the word out of the winning pair.  To handle the `-1` case we could insert a dummy pair into the filtered list with `-1` for the word and `-Infinity` for the letter count.  If the list is otherwise empty, then we will choose this one.

And doing this might lead us to add some defaulting behavior to `maximumBy`, which right now is limited to numbers, but ideally should work with anything we can compare using `<`.  If we defaulted our lower bound of `-Infinity`, but allowing override, and paired that with a default value for an empty list, then we could probably do the above in a fairly simple way.<sup>1</sup>

But that feels a bit overcomplicated.  Perhaps a simpler approach would be to simply perform the code as above, then test if the resulting word has any repeated letter.  While we could track this through the function, I think the simplest version would be to call `letterCount` again on it.  So this is how I would probably choose to write this function:

```js
const maxBy = (fn) => (xs) => xs .reduce (
  ({m, r}, x) => {const v = fn(x); return v > m ? {m: v, r: x} : {m, r}}, 
  {m: -Infinity}
) .r

const letterCount = ([...cs]) => 
  cs .reduce ((a, c) => {a [c] = (a [c] || 0) + 1; return a}, {})

const maxLetterCount = (cs) => 
  Math .max (... Object .values (letterCount (cs)))

const letterCountI = (s, target = maxBy (maxLetterCount) (s .split (/\s+/))) =>
  maxLetterCount (target) > 1 ? target : -1

console .log (letterCountI ("Today, is the greatest day ever!"))
console .log (letterCountI ("Hello Apple Pie"))
console .log (letterCountI ("Today, is the day!"))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> That might look like this (untested) version:

```js
const maximumBy = (fn, {dfltVal = '', lowBound = -Infinity} = {}) => (xs) => xs .reduce (
  ({m, r}, x) => {const v = fn(x); return v > m ? {m: v, r: x} : {m, r}}, 
  {m: lowBound, r: dfltVal}
) .r
```

Answer (score -1):

Staying with the OP's [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach one would provide a single function which incorporates two specific nested `reduce` tasks responsible for 1) aggregating the word specific statistics of a sentence and 2) the letter specific statistics for each word.
This approach also ensures the result of `''` (suggested) or `-1` (the OP'S requirement) in case there are only words of unique (non repeating) letters/characters.

```js
function getFirstOccurringWordOfMaximumSameCharacterCount(value) {

  function aggregateCharCountData(wordStats, char, idx, arr) {
    const { charStats } = wordStats;

    // aggregate character specific array.
    (charStats[char] ??= []).push(char);

    if (idx >= (arr.length - 1)) {
      // console.log({ charStats });

      // aggregate maximum character count data
      // at the end of the last character reduce step.
      const maxCharList = Object
        .values(charStats)
        .sort((aCharList, bCharList) =>
          bCharList.length - aCharList.length
        )[0];

      wordStats.maxCharCount = maxCharList.length;
      wordStats.maxCountChar = maxCharList[0];
    }
    return wordStats;
  }
  function aggregateWordSpecificCharCountData(collector, word, idx, arr) {
    const { statistics } = collector;

    statistics.push(
      word
        .split('')
        .reduce(aggregateCharCountData, { word, charStats: {} })
    );
    if (idx >= (arr.length - 1)) {

      // find the first occurring word of maximum same character count
      // at the end of the last word reduce step.
      const wordStats = statistics
        .sort((aWordStats, bWordStats) =>
          bWordStats.maxCharCount - aWordStats.maxCharCount
        )[0];
      // console.log({ statistics });

      collector.result = (wordStats.maxCharCount >= 2)
        ? wordStats.word
        : ''; // : -1;
    }
    return collector;
  }

  const {

    // statistics,
    result,

  } = String(value)
    .split(/\s+/)

    .reduce(aggregateWordSpecificCharCountData, {
      statistics: [],
      result: '',
    });
  // console.log({ statistics });

  return result;
}

console.log([

  'Today is the day.',                  // ''
  'Today, is the greatest day ever!',   // 'greatest'
  'Hello Apple Pie',                    // 'Hello'
  'She sells seashells by the seashore' // 'seashells'

].map(getFirstOccurringWordOfMaximumSameCharacterCount));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```